# Return string when button is pressed in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

There are two buttons. The role of the buttons is to determine whether to search by book title or by author name when searching for a book.

I made a part where the `bookTitleFilterBtn` is disabled when the `authorNameFilterBtn` is pressed.

```
var buttons: [UIButton] { return [bookTitleFilterBtn, authorNameFilterBtn] }
```

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        bookTitleFilterBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonClicked(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        authorNameFilterBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonClicked(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
```

```
func updateButtonsAppearance(allButtons: [UIButton], selectedButton: UIButton) {
        for button in allButtons {
            let isSelected = button == selectedButton

            let currentTitle = button.currentTitle ?? "-"
            let title = NSAttributedString(string: currentTitle, attributes: [.foregroundColor: isSelected ? UIColor.white : UIColor.black])
            button.setAttributedTitle(title, for: .normal)
            button.setTitleColor(isSelected ? .white : .black, for: .normal)
            button.backgroundColor = isSelected ? .red : .white
            button.isHighlighted = isSelected
        }
    }
```

```
@objc func buttonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.updateButtonsAppearance(allButtons: self.buttons, selectedButton: sender)
        }
    }
```

What I want to implement is that "book_title" is returned when bookTitleFilterBtn is pressed, and "author_name" is returned when authorNameFilterBtn is pressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can return any value in button press method, but will not helpful as return value will return to `UIControl` class and you will not able to access it.
2. You can set the tag to button and when button press you can compare the tab and identify which button pressed. Also you can manage button selected status to set background. Here is sample code.

   ```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       bookTitleFilterBtn.tag = 1
       bookTitleFilterBtn.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
       bookTitleFilterBtn.setTitleColor(.white, for: .selected)
       bookTitleFilterBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonClicked(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

       authorNameFilterBtn.tag = 2
       authorNameFilterBtn.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
       authorNameFilterBtn.setTitleColor(.white, for: .selected)
       authorNameFilterBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonClicked(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
   }




   @objc func buttonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {

       if sender.tag == 1{
           bookTitleFilterBtn.isSelected = true
           authorNameFilterBtn.isSelected = false
       }else{
           bookTitleFilterBtn.isSelected = false
           authorNameFilterBtn.isSelected = true
       }
   }
   ```
3. No need to call `updateButtonsAppearance` in main block as touch event by default in `main` thread.

Comment: Mitesh hit the nail on the head. You only need to configure the buttons one time. You do it in `viewDidLoad` and you tell it the behavior you want for selected and normal. That's it. From there, you just toggle state and the button knows what to do for each state.